# Odd Black Patches and Modifiers Not Appearing in Blender Cycles Render but Appear Fine in Viewport

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting a great render in the preview, but terrible black patches and modifiers such as subsurf not appearing on final render? Below are pictures and .blend file. I've tried applying the subsurf but am still getting terrible black spots.

I appreciate the help!

[image]

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: I've downloaded the blend file, but the textures don't come with it. You might want to go to your blend file and go to File > External Data > Automatically Pack Into .blend and reupload your file.

Comment: I'm away from my computer until tomorrow, but all the materials are just procedural with no images and here is the link to the free hdri world environment texture, I was using the 4k one I believe: https://hdrihaven.com/hdri.php?hdri=balcony Let me know if this works and I can upload again tomorrow! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it myself, there must have been some type messed up topology that was allowing it to preview fine, but then when I went to actually render, everything went haywire. I ended up re-modeling all the bevels around the initial shape and now it renders out fine!

So I guess make sure to do periodic test renders!!